# could not import ... (no required module provides package ".../utils/...")

Tags: go

Ok I'm officially stumped. I've reviewed these 4 similar questions/answers:

[go no required module provides package mux error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842657/go-no-required-module-provides-package-mux-error)

[Could not import ... (no required module provides package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716220/could-not-import-no-required-module-provides-package)

[Could not import local modules in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680470/could-not-import-local-modules-in-golang)

[VSCode: Could not import Golang package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518588/vscode-could-not-import-golang-package)

...and they all basically repeat the same answer of running `go mod init <name>` and `go mod tidy` which I've done numerous times, same issue persists.

I do not have this package uploaded to a github repo, it's just stored locally on my Windows machine. I have run the commands:

`go mod init go_backtest`

`go mod tidy`

...and I am still seeing these all over the place:

[image: issue1]

what's interesting is there is NOT a red underline under the `"go_backtest/strategies"` line:

[image: issue2]

This is what the go.mod file looks like:

```
module go_backtest

go 1.19
```

I'm still a newbie to golang so be kind, but how can I get this thing to "compile" and run (and make those red underlines go away!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in the `utils` directory should belong to the same package `utils`. Those files should have the line `package utils` at the very beginning.

And the import statement is used to import a package instead of a file. So replace

```
"go_backtest/utils/dataFuncs"
"go_backtest/utils/ga"
```

with

```
"go_backtest/utils"
```

Comment: Thank you. I made sure all files in the `utils` folder were from package `utils`, then changed the imports in `main` to `"go_backtest/utils"` and then just used `utils.LoadData()` to call the methods.